# How can I use the minor sign < in a .bat file to take it as text

Tags: php, batch-file, cmd, console

I am creating a php file from a .bat document, the problem is that I need to initialize the php in my document and when using it `<` in batch it takes it as a character of its own, if I put "php" there is no problem, but the Initializer comes with the quotes to the file that I create.

As I do so that in my .bat file I can put the `<` without marking it as my own language?

This is how I create my PHP file

```
@echo off

set file= "test.php"
set /p url= Ingrese la url del iframe: 
set /p height= Ingrese la altura del iframe (px): 

if exist %file% del %file% && goto :create

if not exist %file% goto :create 

:create 

echo <?php > test.php

echo /** >> test.php
echo  * Nota: Si la calculadora no detecta el token del cliente en la configuracion del gateway, no aparecerá en el detalle del producto. >> test.php 
echo  */ >> test.php
echo.

echo /** >> test.php
echo  * Url donde va a apuntar el entorno: Desarrollo, preproducción o producción. >> test.php 
echo  */ >> test.php
echo $crediya_products["Calculadora"] = "%url%"; >> test.php

echo /** >> test.php
echo  * Configuracion de la altura del iframe valor por defecto 240 >> test.php 
echo  */ >> test.php
echo $crediya_products["CalculadoraHeight"] = "%height%"; >> test.php

pause
```

Comment: Please show us at least an example of what you are doing, as it stands I have no idea what you are actually doing

Comment: @RiggsFolly 
Now add how I have my .bat file